# Android Firebase getReference and child

Tags: java, android, firebase

what is reference and child in firebase ?

```
             mSearchedLocationReference = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_SEARCHED_LOCATION);
```

and

```
            DatabaseReference restaurantRef = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_RESTAURANTS);
```

I took the code from https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/data-persistence/firebase-writing-pojos and from what i read :

```
Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_RESTAURANTS = "Restaurants"
Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_SEARCHED_LOCATION = "SearchedLocation"
```

Restaurants and SearchedLocation both are a Node (or a Table in RDBMS perspective) , but why restaurant is called by reference and searchedLocation is called by child.

the other link which shows the searchedLocation child : https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/data-persistence/firebase-reading-data-and-event-listeners

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can write

```
FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference().child(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_RESTAURANTS);
```

it will be the same as

```
 FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_RESTAURANTS);
```

Comment: oh i see, then what is the different between reference and child ?

Comment: A child is a reference - to the child.

Comment: Despite the fact that the OP understood your answer, I still think it's not clear. The OP asked, "what is reference and child in firebase ?" And you didn't give any explicit answer. Also "A child is a reference - to the child" - Well, defining what is `A` by describing `A` isn't clear.